# Dojo set validation from javascript

Tags: javascript, validation, dojo

I have a select list when i select the '*phone number*' option i set **regExp** option in the number field so the user must enter a *phone number* in the required format. I also have an '*email*' option in he select list and when selected i want to set the **data-dojo-props** for the number field.

In other words i am using one **validationTextField** to caputre both phone numbers and email address. However when the **regExp** is set it does not take the required effect and when the **data-dojo-props** is set for email it does not take the required effect. In both options if a valid value is entered or an invalid value is entered the **validator** does however show an error (*red exclamation mark on field*).

**Code**

```
<input type="text" required="true" name="contactString"
id="contactStringId" placeholder="Your Contact Number"
data-dojo-type="dijit/form/ValidationTextBox"                   
missingMessage="Please Enter Your Contact Number"
title="Contact Number / Email Address :" style="width: 25em;"/>
```

```javascript
 if (contactType.match(/^email|e-mail|mail.*$/)){
        dijit.byId('contactStringId').attr('invalidMessage', 'Invalid ' + contactType.toProperCase() +' Format: www.local-part@domain.com');                    
        dijit.byId('contactStringId').set('data-dojo-props', 'validator:dojox/validate/isEmailAddress');            
        console.log('email settings set');

    }else if(contactType.match(/^cell|home|work|fax|office.*$/)){
        dijit.byId('contactStringId').attr('invalidMessage', 'Invalid ' + contactType.toProperCase() +' Format: (xxx)-xxx-xxxx');   
        dijit.byId('contactStringId').set('regExp', '^[0-9]\d{2}-\d{3}-\d{4}$');        
        console.log('phone number settings set');           
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you're setting dojo widget properties programmatically, you don't set data-dojo-props, you normally set the actual attribute you want to set. So you would do:

```
dijit.byId('contactStringId').set("validator", /*whatever validator you want here*/);
```

A better way to do this is simply by doing this:

```
var contactStringBox = dijit.byId('contactStringId');
contactStringBox.validator = function() {
  /*
   *whatever validation code you want here
   * like if(this.value === "test") { return false;}
   */
}
```

Comment: Well, you can use data-dojo-props, but that goes in the declarative syntax (i.e. in your markup, not in your javascript)...

Comment: Ah yes, sorry forgot to clarify that this is only true only when doing it programmatically. Thanks Phillipe and modified my answer.